# Android: shared lib .../libstlport_shared.so already loaded with same cl (sqlcipher related)

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I'm receiving this debug messages each time I access to the database:

```
05-26 19:48:54.330: D/dalvikvm(24695): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.primerprograma-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x42131f38<br>
05-26 19:48:54.330: D/dalvikvm(24695): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.example.primerprograma-2/libstlport_shared.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42131f38<br>
05-26 19:48:54.330: D/dalvikvm(24695): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.primerprograma-2/libsqlcipher_android.so 0x42131f38<br>
05-26 19:48:54.330: D/dalvikvm(24695): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.example.primerprograma-2/libsqlcipher_android.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42131f38<br>
05-26 19:48:54.330: D/dalvikvm(24695): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.primerprograma-2/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so 0x42131f38<br>
05-26 19:48:54.330: D/dalvikvm(24695): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.example.primerprograma-2/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42131f38
```

This started happening when I implemented SQLCipher library on my project. I've been searching everywhere for information about this 'error' (don't look actually like an error, though) and I don't know how to get rid of it. My app constantly access the database so the log is really difficult to read with all those messages showing up.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Trying to limit log clutter is a noble goal, but it is ultimately only an advisory message, not an "error" at all.

Answer (score 1):

SQLCipher for Android loads 3 native libraries in the call to [`SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(...)`](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/src/net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase.java#L110).  Calling this method again when the native libraries are already loaded does not reload the library, you should only need to do this once within your application.

Comment: I was having some performance issues when moving between activities. When I studied the logs I noticed I was getting this warning, and sure enough I was calling LoadLibs multiple times. Unfortunately this didn't resolve my performance issues :-(, but certainly needed doing. Thanks.